# Add 1Hour to java.sql.timeStamp in gsp or groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, timestamp-with-timezone

I convert new Date() to GMT. Now I need to add 1 hour to GMT time. The class is java.sql.timeStamp. How do I add 1 hour to the nowGMT variable in grails. I have magic number plugin installed in my project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

...

Timestamp plusOne = use( TimeCategory ) { nowGMT + 1.hour }.toTimestamp()
```

Comment: @tim_yates.i tried it. But can i do this calculation directly in .gsp file instead of putting it controller and passing it in the view?

Comment: @user1610812 you shouldn't do calculations in the view, so I'd put it in the controller

Comment: Recently I've done it in view as per follows:

1. In page import:

<%@ page import="website.ecommerce.SalesOrder; groovy.time.TimeCategory" %>

2. <td><g:formatDate date="${use( TimeCategory ) { salesOrderInstance.orderDate + 6.hour }}" format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"/></td>